# Owl carousel: image link doesn't click

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

The image link doesn't click
https://www.audubon.org/native-plants/search?zipcode=77092

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlrDj.png)

I use Owl carousel v2.
My options:

```js
        self.owlCarousel({
          items: 2,
          nav:true,
          pagination: false,
          autoWidth: true,
          margin: 10,
          navText: ["<i class=\"indicator-left icon-arrow-left\"></i>", "<i class=\"indicator-right icon-arrow-right\"></i>"],
          responsive : {
            0 : {
              items: 1,
              autoWidth: false
            },

            320 : {
              items: 2,
              autoWidth: false
            },

            580: {
              items: 3,
              autoWidth: false
            },

            602 : {
              items: 2,
              autoWidth: true
            }
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Solution]

**My solution:**
Please look at the image above.
So I removed links in the figure and add after.

Comment: Solution for same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69902842/2877427